# castor Mapping to JAXB Schema

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, castor

How to convert (or reuse) castor mapping in jaxb projects (maby convert Mapping to Scheme)? I need it for unmarshalling source xml with SAXSource instead of InputStream. I know about castor-1.3.3rc1 and SAXSource support, but it still unstable for big files.